# How do I shrink the content of this iFrame?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need to have a webpage where 6 cams are displayed on one webpage. I can do this with iframes, but the content of the iframes are still fullscreen. How can I shrink them to fit the iFrame window?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Spycam</title>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="(ip adress here)"
width="640px" height="480px">

</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to control the contents of the iframe, only the iframe itself.  If the contents of the iframes are content that you control (i.e. can edit the HTML/CSS), then you can change the videos on the pages themselves.

Comment: I do not have control over the webpages in the iframes. I can only link them inside of the iframe. Is there no way to shrink the content at all?

Comment: NO. There's a security policy. You can't modify content of other domain different of your page.

Comment: The direct output of the camera is a fullscreen webpage with the video feed. Any idea what I could try?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to just have 6 different iframes, one with each cam, and then align those iframes however you want.